# Como copiar elementos de un contenedor a otro en javascript?

Tags: javascript

Estoy trabajando en un servicio web con HTML, CSS y JavaScript.
Tengo una lista en un cierto con tenedor en donde cada elemento de la lista es una imagen. En cada una de estas imágenes se puede hacer clic.

La idea entonces es que se pueda hacer clic en cada imagen y pasarlas a un contenedor nuevo.

Codigo HTML con la lista de imagenes:

```
<ul>
   <li id="primerImagen">
    <input type="image" src="pictures/primerImagen.png">
   </li>
   <li id="segundaImagen">
     <input type="image" src="pictures/segundaImagen.png">
   </li>
   <li id="tercerImagen">
     <input type="image" src="pictures/tercerImagen.png">
   </li>
</ul>
```

De la siguiente manera logro que las imágenes aparezcan en un box nuevo

```
var contenedor = document.getElementById("tableBox2");
document.querySelectorAll('input[type="image"]').forEach(function(image) {
  var imagenes = document.createElement("image");
  image.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    contenedor.appendChild(this);
  });
});
```

El problema es que no estoy logrando que las imágenes pasen de un lugar a otro sin eliminarlas del a lista original. Alguna sugerencia de como lograr esto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si  lo que quieres es lograr pasar la imagen a otro contenedor sin que se elimine del primero, deberás crear un crear una copia del primero y añadirla a tu segundo contenedor, la función *cloneNode()* te será util:

```
contenedor.appendChild(this.cloneNode());
```

De esta forma no reasignas el nodo, sino que creas una copia y esta la añades a otro contenedor.

Puedes encontrar más info [Aquí](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_methods.asp). Espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: La idea en realidad es que NO se elimine de la original.  El codigo que puse arriba hace eso justamente.

Comment: Ok, entendí mal la idea, creo que de esta forma lo podrás lograr, saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda ! voy a intentar esto mismo.

Comment: Hola, te hago otra consulta... a las imágenes que agrego en el nuevo box, hay alguna forma de darles cierto estilo? por que por lo que veo reciben el estilo que tienen las imágenes originales y ni siquiera se realizan esos estilos en el box nuevo

Comment: Claro que sí, solo guardas la copia en alguna varible : `var imagen = this.cloneNode()`  y le aplicas el estilo que desees con la propiedad style: `imagen.style = "..."` y luego añades a tu contenedor.